# Can't figure out background-image: url();

Tags: css

I'm extremely new to html and css. My 6 year old recently decided he wants to become a barber, so I decided to use this as a chance to practice and create a mock business page for him.

I can't seem to get the background image to show up but the color works perfectly fine. I used the Inspect tool on Chrome and it says the image file wasn't found. This means the path is incorrect, right?

Image path: /Users/myname/Documents/CaydenCutz/img/barbershop.png

CSS file path:/Users/myname/Documents/CaydenCutz/CayStyleSheet.css

I've tried:

```
url(/img/barbershop.png⁩⁩);
url(../img/barbershop.png⁩⁩);
url(../../img/barbershop.png⁩⁩);
url(/img/barbershop.png⁩⁩);
url("../../img/barbershop.png⁩⁩");
url("../img/barbershop.png"⁩⁩);
url("/img/barbershop.png"⁩⁩);
url("barbershop.png⁩⁩");
url(barbershop.png⁩⁩);
url(/Users/myname/Documents/CaydenCutz/img/barbershop.png⁩⁩);
url(img/barbershop.png);
url(img/barbershop.png);
```

The image was initially .jpg but I converted it to .png after naively thinking that'd help.

The code for now:

```
.header {
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    to bottom left,
    rgba(252, 228, 5, 0.7),
    rgba(242, 199, 15, 0.7)),
    url(/img/barbershop.png⁩⁩);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top;
```

I expected the image to show up behind the gradient, but I'm just getting the color. 
I know the solution is going to be something extremely simple. But I can't seem to figure it out right now.

Comment: Try this `background: url('/Users/myname/Documents/CaydenCutz/img/barbershop.png');`

Comment: press f12 in your browser, which will bring up the developer tools. look in the console.. you might be able to see where the browser is looking for the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value given to `url()` needs to be a URL that is resolvable relative to the CSS file, or an absolute URL (for example, an external URL). So, assume you have this structure:

- site root

  - CSS folder

    - styles.css
  - img folder

    - background.png

Given that, for url() to find the file correctly, you would be able to use one of these:

```
url(../img/background.png)
```

or

```
url(/img/background.png)
```

Quotes are only required if the path contains spaces or other reserved characters, but you really should avoid those anyway.

You may find the MDN documentation worth reading:

- background: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background
- url(): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/url

Answer (score 0):

i think there is some special character involved in URL 
when i copied your code it showing ( see after .png)

[image]

copy this and change you images name, its working fine

```
height: 100vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient( to bottom left, rgba(252, 228, 5, 0.7), rgba(242, 199, 15, 0.7)), url('img/BG0.png');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top;
```

copy this and change you images name